# Why does `border-collapse:collapse` cause adjacent cells to have a top border when one isn't drawn

Tags: html, google-chrome, html-table, border

I have the following HTML:

```
<table style="table-layout: fixed;width: 768px;border-collapse: collapse !important;">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="2"></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
  <th 
    colspan="1" 
    style="border-right: 1px solid black; border-top: 1px solid black;">abc</th><th colspan="20">
  </th>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

(can be run here https://jsfiddle.net/vchelaru/nhxye9mj/11/)

In Chrome (79.0.3945.117), the top border extends to the right beyond the row that has `border-top: 10x solid black;` as shown in the following picture:

[image]

Firefox and IE render the table as I would expect:

[image]

Note that if I remove the `border-collapse: collapse` style, the border does not extend to the right beyond the first column, but I need to have borders collapsed.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing first row of the table to explicitly list the number of columns rather than a single column with a colspan seems to fix the problem:

```
<table style="table-layout: fixed;width: 768px;border-collapse: collapse !important;">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th/><th/>
    </tr>
</thead>
...
```